# atomic_init is not thread safe in C, so why does it exist?

Tags: c, atomic

The C17 standard, section 7.17.2.2, states the below regarding`void atomic_init(volatile A *obj, C value)` defined in `<stdatomic.h>`:

> Although this function initializes an atomic object, it does not avoid data races; concurrent access to the variable being initialized, even via an atomic operation, constitutes a data race.

Since the whole point of having atomic objects and atomic operations is to avoid data races, why does the `atomic_init` function exist? For example, why not do the below?

```
_Atomic int x = 7;
```

Instead of:

```
_Atomic int x; 
atomic_init(&x, 7);
```

Also, why is it called `atomic_init` when it really is an assignment?

Comment: it says that creation and init of it is not race free. So do that before firing up threads

Comment: @pm100 sure, but that is my point. Why is it there? Since I can just do _Atomic int x = 7; and then fire up my threads?

Comment: The answer is in exactly the passage you cited: "The `atomic_init` generic function initializes the atomic object [...] **while also initializing any additional state that the implementation might need** to carry for the atomic object.". It exists for generality's sake on platforms where atomics are more complicated

Comment: your main question was , why does atomic_int exist if its not thread safe, now you ask, "if i dont use it correctly will it work", probably not

Comment: @alter_igel so does that mean that the plain _Atomic int x = 7 does NOT do an initialization of the additional state that the implementation might need to carry for the atomic object x?

Comment: `atomic_init` would be required for dynamically allocated vars

Comment: I've used `stdatomic.h` primitives before but I've never used `atomic_init` before. I've always used `atomic_store`. I guess that's because in `stdatomic.h` from `gcc` we have: `#define atomic_init(PTR, VAL) atomic_store_explicit (PTR, VAL, __ATOMIC_RELAXED)`

Comment: @CraigEstey good observation. So, in the case of gcc, atomic_init is thread-safe and doesn't have data race issue.

Comment: Why would any other thread access the variable before it has been initialized? That's not a re-entrancy problem, it's a program design problem. Similarly you can't access a high level mutex before it has been initialized either, also not a re-entrancy problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Atomic` objects may have hidden fields used to achieve the desired semantics, and those need to be initialized somehow. This can be achieved by using a C variable initializer or by using `atomic_init`.

For a static or automatic variable, that provides two options:

```c
_Atomic int x = 7;
```

```c
_Atomic int x; 
atomic_init( &x, 7 );
```

But that only leaves one option for dynamically-allocated variables.

```c
_Atomic int *p = malloc( sizeof( _Atomic int ) );
atomic_init( p, 7 );
```

Comment: since atomic_init is not thread safe, atomic_init(&(p->x), 7) is the same as p->x = 7, is  it not?

Comment: That doesn't init

Comment: The issue isn't with the initialization of `x`, but with the initialization relating to allowing atomic operations to work on the object, as @alter_igel mentions in the comments. I believe this is relevant for platforms where atomic operations aren't supported in hardware, and a mutex (or similar locking mechanism) needs to be created per-atomic object to support atomic operations on it. Unsure what platforms exist with this restriction, however.

Comment: @ikegami what do you mean it doesn't init? since we're using malloc, it is always an assignment, whether we are doing p->x = 7 or atomic_init(&(p->x), 7).

Comment: Why do you think `atomic_init` is "just an assignment"??? After being been told otherwise (twice)?

Comment: I thought the definition of initialization is giving a value during object construction and not after the object is constructed (in this case malloc).

Comment: Initialization and assignment are two different things -- depending on implementation details they might end up being the same thing under the hood or they might not.  C  does not provide any way of initializing objects in dynamic memory (allocated with malloc), so if an implementation of a type needs initialization and assignment to be different, it needs to provide a special way of doing that.  `atomic_init` provides a standard way of doing that for _Atomic objects, allowing an implementation to have them be different in a reasonably portable way.

Comment: Re "*I thought the definition of initialization is giving a value during object construction*", It's just giving it its initial value. It's not necessary during construction. Specifically, `malloc` DOESN'T initialize the memory space it allocates. (`calloc` initializes it to zero bytes, but that doesn't mean it's properly initialized for an Atomic.)

Comment: The wording of the C standard is somewhat unclear here.  If you want to put an `_Atomic int` in malloc'ed memory, it's in "indeterminate state" until `atomic_init` is performed.  As I interpret that, it means you can't safely do *anything* with it until after `atomic_init`; in particular, trying to load or store it would cause UB.  So in normal code, you'd do your `atomic_init` before accessing it, and before passing the address to any other thread that might access it.  The "not thread safe" just means "don't try to have multiple threads racing to do the init".